# Formalizing conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I need help to translate into a conditional exepectation the following problem:

We have an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ of size M (say $\mathcal{M} = [0, M]$). For each element $x \in \mathcal{M}$ I define $\theta(x)$ which is the score of each element of my interval.
I want these scores to follow a given distribution with cdf $F$. For each subset $\mu$ of $\mathcal{M}$, I would like to define the average value of $\theta$ over this subset.

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\theta(x) \left|x \in \mu \right. \right] 
$$

How can I calculate this? My first intuition is to do

$$
\int_{x \in \mu(x)}{\theta(x) dF(x)}
$$

But it just seems like I am mixing different measures. I would really appreciate some help to formalize this and relate this to the theory of probability.

Thank you for your help.

T.

Comment: The average value of the function $\theta:x\mapsto\theta(x)$ over the set $\mu\subseteq\mathcal M$ of positive measure $|\mu|$ is by definition $$\frac1{|\mu|}\int_\mu\theta(x)\,dx$$ Nothing probabilistic in there.

Comment: $\theta$ is a random variable.

Comment: Yeah I know, and the solution does not use this.